# background-image for a div showing in IE but not in chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, css

here i am developing a project using VS2010 ultimate and was building some views when i came across this problem. i am defining background-image for some div classes like .jpg,.png but they are being visible only in IE6 and not on chrome
here is the div class

```
<div class="log_pad">
```

and here its style

```
.log_pad 
{
background-image: url('~/App_Data/images/login_pallete.png') no-repeat;
width: 478px;
height: 397px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: give correct path and try with `../` if need until you get the image

Comment: You can't use the `~/` path on static files. Just on files that are going to be processed, like .aspx

Answer (score 1):

Probably has to do with your `url` path for `background-image`.  What's with the `~/` at the beginning?

`background-image` CSS url path is relative to the location of the css file, so if your css file is in the base directory and your image is in subfolder `App_Data/images` you should type it like that, not with the `~/` at the beginning (I'm not sure about the ~ but a `/` at the start of a relative file path returns you to the root directory).  If your css is in a sibling folder to `App_Data/` like `css/` you would write it as `url(../App_Data/images/login_pallete.png`).  I would recommend trying to write it as a true relative path to the CSS file rather than starting at the root as a way of troubleshooting.

See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/) for more info.  If that is not the issue, it is due to something else you did not post here.

Comment: The `~/` means the web application root folder in ASP.NET. Which of course won't work on static pages, like CSS, JS, etc, unless you work out a mapping/replacing routine.

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something like that, thanks. In pure CSS the same shortcut to root is just `/`.  I don't know much about ASPX or his file structure so I can't comment on that specifically but I'm still assuming the file path is the culprit because everything else he posted looks fine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I just pointed out because if you're not used to ASP.NET, that shortcut makes no sense at all. :)